# How to write a library similar to jquery in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am going to write a lightweight library for some simple pages with typescript.However, I was hindered, and I did not know how to deal with these problems

I use a decorator to extend the methods of this class, but I can't call them in the constructor, and the editor prompts me in the 'each' method with "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'Selector'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'Selector'."

```
function addArrayMethods(target: Function) {
  target.prototype.push = Array.prototype.push
  target.prototype.splice = Array.prototype.splice
}

@addArrayMethods
class Selector {
  length: number = 0

  selector!: string;

  constructor(sth: string | HTMLElement) {
    if (typeof sth === 'string') {
      this.selector = sth
      this.push.apply(this, document.querySelectorAll(sth)) // error1
    } else {
      this.push(sth) // error1
    }
  }

  each(callback: (value: any, index: number) => void): void {
    let i: number = -1
    const len: number = this.length
    while (++i < len) {
      callback(this[i], i) // error2 this[i]
    }
  }
}
```

error1: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Selector'.

error2: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'Selector'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'Selector'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorators do not by themselves change TypeScript's understanding to the decorated types; you still have to define the method `push` etc. on your `Selector` class. Perhaps the easiest way to do this is by adding an interface:

```
interface Selector {
    push(...items: any[]): number;
    splice(start: number, deleteCount?: number): any[];
    [index: number]: any;
}
```

Add this to your code and it will do the job. The last definition is for providing the index signature needed for `this[i]` usage.